# How to perform Dynamic database creation based on XML using php

Tags: php

EXAMPLE -

```html
   <Properties>

<Property>


<Refnumber>…..

<Number>…



<Bulletpoints>

<BulletPoint>List of important items</BulletPoint> 
<BulletPoint>Up to 12 BulletPoint nodes</BulletPoint>

</Bulletpoints>


<Rooms>

<Room>

<Title>name of room 

</Room>

</Rooms>




<Amenity>
 <id> </id>

</Amenity>

</Property>

</Properties>


<Amenities>

<Amenity>

<id </id> 

<Types>

<Type> </Type>

</Types>

</Amenity>

</Amenities>
```

How to perform Dynamic database creation based on XML with different tag and tags having subtags using php. and is it compulsory to close each tag?? as per the above xml code ,, some tags were not closed.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you are looking for please, and (ideally) an attempt at the problem? You'll probably need to explain the "different tags" and "subtags", it is not clear what they mean.

Comment: Your XML seems to be plain English. There can be no way to analyze and implement a phrase like '<BulletPoint>Up to 12 BulletPoint nodes</BulletPoint>' programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not a valid XML (missing closing tags) you won't be able to parse it properly.

If you have a valid XML file you can use SimpleXML or any other PHP based XML library to parse your document and create the apropriate table structure.

Comment: can u gave me an appropriate way to create a table structure for the above xml (xml file with proper closing tag)